# Preferred method to use two names to call the same function in C

Tags: c, function, embedded

I know there are at least three popular methods to call the same function with multiple names.  I haven't actually heard of someone using the fourth method for this purpose.

**1). Could use #defines:**

```
int my_function (int);


#define my_func my_function
```

OR

```
#define my_func(int (a)) my_function(int (a))
```

**2). Embedded function calls are another possibility:**

```
int my_func(int a) {
    return my_function(a);
}
```

**3). Use a weak alias in the linker:**

```
int my_func(int a) __attribute__((weak, alias("my_function")));
```

**4). Function pointers:**

```
int (* const my_func)(int) = my_function;
```

The reason I need multiple names is for a mathematical library that has multiple implementations of the same method.

For example, I need an efficient method to calculate the square root of a scalar floating point number.  So I could just use math.h's sqrt().  This is not very efficient.  So I write one or two other methods, such as one using Newton's Method.  The problem is each technique is better on certain processors (in my case microcontrollers).  So I want the compilation process to choose the best method.

I think this means it would be best to use either the macros or the weak alias since those techniques could easily be grouped in a few #ifdef statements in the header files.  This simplifies maintenance (relatively).  It is also possible to do using the function pointers, but it would have to be in the source file with extern declarations of the general functions in the header file.

Which do you think is the better method?

---

**Edit:**

From the proposed solutions, there appears to be two important questions that I did not address.

**Q. Are the users working primarily in C/C++?**

**A.** All known development will be in C/C++ or assembly.  I am designing this library for my own personal use, mostly for work on bare metal projects.  There will be either no or minimal operating system features.  There is a remote possibility of using this in full blown operating systems, which would require consideration of language bindings.  Since this is for personal growth, it would be advantageous to learn library development on popular embedded operating systems.

**Q. Are the users going to need/want an exposed library?**

**A.** So far, yes.  Since it is just me, I want to make direct modifications for each processor I use after testing.  This is where the test suite would be useful.  So an exposed library would help somewhat.  Additionally, each "optimal implementation" for  particular function may have a failing conditions.  At this point, it has to be decided who fixes the problem: the user or the library designer.  A user would need an exposed library to work around failing conditions.  I am both the "user" and "library designer".  It would almost be better to allow for both.  Then non-realtime applications could let the library solve all of stability problems as they come up, but real-time applications would be empowered to consider algorithm speed/space vs. algorithm stability.

Comment: not too sure I understand your question. you are talking about having multiple functions doing different things, and then you example code describes how you can have multiple names on the same function. also, if i was to choose from any of the above methods I would choose the one that makes it the most clear that they are the same, if someone else would want to extend your code. 1 and 3 seem pretty clear in terms of that.

Comment: @chikuba, I have multiple implementations for a certain functionality (calculating the square-root), but I want to use a generic sqrt() call to use the best implementation for that processor.  I will "tell" the compiler which implementation is the correct one for each processor (or processor family).

Comment: oh yes ofc. I would use the define approach even though I can have some downsides as @eugen stated (http://www.edaboard.com/thread56142.html)

Comment: I am missing something -- why can't you just build the bundle of optimized functions as a library, and link in the right library based on the microcontroller?  Why undertake this complexity & expose all these things to your application?  Just let your application call sqrt(), and you decide (at link time) where it comes from.  Believe me, these are the waters I swim in, I do this all the time.

Comment: your second method in 1. where you try to be type safe, I guess, is not C but C++. In any case the compiler will tell you all by himself if the expression is not assignment compatible to `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the intended audience for your library, I suggest you chose between 2 alternatives:

1. If the consumer of your library is guaranteed to be `C`ish, use `#define sqrt newton_sqrt` for optimal readability
2. If some consumers of your library are **not** of the C variety (think bindings to Dephi, .NET, whatever) try to avoid consumer-visible `#defines`. This is a major PITA for bindings, as macros are not visible on the binary - embedded function calls are the most binding-friendly.

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative would be to move the functionality into a separately compiled library optimised for each different architecture and then just link to this library during compilation.  This would allow the project code to remain unchanged.

Comment: +1, Just left a comment suggesting this & now I come down & see that you suggested the exact same thing.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is this. In header file (.h):

```
 int function(void);
```

In the source file (.c):

```
static int function_implementation_a(void);
static int function_implementation_b(void);
static int function_implementation_c(void);

#if ARCH == ARCH_A
int function(void)
{
    return function_implementation_a(); 
}
#elif ARCH == ARCH_B
int function(void)
{
    return function_implementation_b();
}
#else
int function(void)
{
    return function_implementation_c();
}
#endif // ARCH
```

Static functions called once are often inlined by the implementation. This is the case for example with `gcc` by default :   `-finline-functions-called-once` is enabled even in `-O0`. The static functions that are not called are also usually not included in the final binary.

Note that I don't put the `#if` and `#else` in a single `function` body because I find the code more readable when `#if` directives are outside the functions body.

Note this way works better with embedded code where libraries are usually distributed in their source form.

Answer (score 3):

I usually like to solve this with a single declaration in a header file with a different source file for each architecture/processor-type.  Then I just have the build system (usually GNU make) choose the right source file.

I usually split the source tree into separate directories for common code and for target-specific code.  For instance, my current project has a toplevel directory `Project1` and underneath it are `include`, `common`, `arm`, and `host` directories.  For `arm` and `host`, the Makefile looks for source in the proper directory based on the target.

I think this makes it easier to navigate the code since I don't have to look up weak symbols or preprocessor definitions to see what functions are actually getting called.  It also avoids the ugliness of function wrappers and the potential performance hit of function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You might you create a test suite for all algorithms and run it on the target to determine which are the best performing, then have the test suite automatically generate the necessary linker aliases (method 3).

Beyond that a simple #define (method 1) probably the simplest, and will not and any potential overhead.  It does however expose to the library user that there might be multiple implementations, which may be undesirable.

Personally, since only one implementation of each function is likley to be optimal on any specific target, I'd use the test suite to determine the required versions for each target and build a separate library for each target with only those one version of each function the correct function name directly.